# Android kotlin eliminate spaces before optional string placeholder

Tags: android, kotlin

Based on a string with multiple placeholders:

```
<string name="customer_info">Info: %1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s; ID=%5$s</string>
```

2, 3 and 4 may mostly be empty so without doing anything with the spaces I would end with this:

```
Info: John   ; ID=0293840
What I need: Info: John; ID=0293840
```

Solution 1 = Divide the string in 3:

```
<string name="customer_info">%1$s%2$s</string>
<string name="customer_info_part1">Info: %1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s</string>
<string name="customer_info_part2">; ID 1%s</string>
```

Is there a better solution using only one string?

I tried using regex: `.replace("\\s+".toRegex(), " ")` but this leads to `Info: John ; ID=0293840` and I'm not sure if using regex in a view holder of list items would be better anyways.

Comment: `Info: %1$s; ID=%2$s`, Do whatever you want to merge the first 4 strings into one string before feeding to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `Info: %1$s; ID=%2$s` as the format string and then something like

```
yourInfosAsList
    .filterNot { it.isNullOrEmpty() }
    .joinToString(separator = " ")
```

to process the non-empty info items to a space-separated string.

Comment: What do you mean with "yourInfosAsList" ?

Comment: Whatever you have in those four values, e.g. `listOf("1", "2", /* 3 = empty */ "", "4")`

Comment: This solution is also better because you need only one string to be translated instead of two, thanks.